# Angularjs Get value of Repeated button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button

I have a simple html table for every x in names. x represent an Object with a few attributes. So one row of this table is filled with: Name, id and so on. I also get one button for every row(Object). But how can I check wich button is pressed? How can I get a value from this button?
For example there is one row with name: Michael, id: 1 and one button. If I press the button I want a var with the id:1 in my app.controller.

HTML code

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:name">
        <div id="kartei">{{ x.artikelName }}{{ x.artikelBeschreibung }}{{ x.artikelPreis }}{{ x.angebotNummer }}{{ x.kundenMail }}</div>

        <div id="Kaufen" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="angebotKaufen">
            <button ng-model="kaufbutton" type="button" ng-click="submit()" ng-value="{{ x.angebotNummer }}">kaufe {{ x.angebotNummer }}</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
app.controller("angebotKaufen", function($scope, $location){
$scope.submit = function(){
    console.log($scope.kaufbutton);
    // Kaufen klicken
    // id infos von der datenbank bekkomen
    // kaufen weiterleiten      

};
```

Comment: Inside your submit you can pass x.id. Then you should be able to get the id whenever it is clicked. Are you facing any problem with it?

Comment: yeah that helped. now i can access the id thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should just pass kaufbutton through the function.

Html

```
<ul >
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:name">
  <div id="kartei">{{ x.artikelName }}{{ x.artikelBeschreibung  }}{{ x.artikelPreis  }}{{ x.angebotNummer  }}{{ x.kundenMail  }}</div>

<div id="Kaufen" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="angebotKaufen">
<button ng-model="kaufbutton" type="button" ng-click="submit($event, kaufbutton)" ng-value="{{ x.angebotNummer }}" >kaufe {{ x.angebotNummer }}</button>
</div>


</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Code

```
app.controller("angebotKaufen", function($scope, $location){
    $scope.submit = function($event, kaufbutton){
        $event.preventDefault();//just in case you need this
        console.log(kaufbutton);
        // Kaufen klicken
        // id infos von der datenbank bekkomen
        // kaufen weiterleiten      
    }; 


});
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have in controller `clients` and `submit` function:

```
$scope.submit = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
}

$scope.clients = [{
    'name': 'Michael',
    'id': 1
}, {
    'name': 'Karl',
    'id': 2
}];
```

then we just pass `id` as argument of `submit`:

```
<div ng-repeat="client in clients">
    {{client.name}} {{client.id}} <button ng-click="submit(client.id)">Submit</button>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/quk7t660/